# Работа с JTree: обработать дерево

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.
У меня есть дерево но не получается его обработать. Есть обработчик только он вешается на все дерево и на отдельных его потомков не получается повесить работу, что бы при нажатии на некоторого потомка выдавало данные именно те которые надо. Как так сделать??

Само дерево.

```
JTree tree = new JTree();       
    tree.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    tree.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Персонал") {
        {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node_1;
            node_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Руководство");
            node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Директор"));
            node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Заместитель"));
            node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Нач.отделов"));
            add(node_1);
            add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Диспетчерская"));
            add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Планово-аналитический"));
            add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Бугалтерия"));
            add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Отдел кадров"));
        }       
    }));

    tree.setToolTipText("");
    tree.setVisibleRowCount(40);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я, когда с деревом работал, вешал `TreeSelectionListener` на всё дерево, узнавал выбранный лист через `getLastSelectedPathComponent()` и уже в зависимости от того, что выбрано, производил обработку. Других вариантов особо не вижу. У `DefaultMutableTreeNode`, как я понимаю, нет методов обработки события выделения. Поправьте меня, если я не прав.

Comment: @Yuri_Prime
А можно какой то пример кода?

Comment: Вот то, что сделано у меня. 
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e){
  DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) 
    this.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
  if(selectedNode != null){
  //Проверяем, что за лист выбрали 
                ///и выполняем какие-либо действия
                }
 }

Comment: @Yuri_Prime
Большое спасибо!